# How to plot the answer obtained from NDSolve

Tags: plotting

```
cf = 200000000;
α = .7;
r = 0.4;
g0 = 1;
g1[t_] := g0 Sin[t/τ];
g2[t_] := -g0 Cos[t/τ];
γc1 = 000 Pi;
γc2 = 000 Pi;
γf = 44000 Pi;
τ = 1;
ξi = {{Re[α]}, {Im[α]}};
ai = {{E^(-2 r), 0}, {0, E^(2 r)}};
hassan = Table[{L, FSR = Pi (cf/L);
   γ1 = (2 γf g1[t]^2)/FSR;
   γ2 = (2 γf g2[t]^2)/FSR;
   γ12 = (2 γf g1[t] g2[t])/FSR;
   sol1 = 
    NDSolve[{m1'[t] == (-γc1 + γ1/2) m1[t] - 
        g1[t] f0[t] - γ12/2 m2[t], 
      f0'[t] == -(γf/2 f0[t] + g1[t] m1[t] + g2[t] m2[t]), 
      m2'[t] == (-γc2 + γ2/2) m2[t] - 
        g2[t] f0[t] - γ12/2 m1[t], m1[0] == 1, f0[0] == 0, 
      m2[0] == 0}, {m1, m2, f0}, {t, 0, (Pi/2 ) τ}];
   MM[t_] = Evaluate[m2[t] /. sol1[[1]]];
   ans = MM[(Pi/2) τ];
    ξf = (ans) ξi;
   af = (.75) (ans^10) (ai);
   ξ1 = ξi - ξf;
   ξT1 = Transpose[ξ1];
   det = Det[ai + af];
   inv = Inverse[ai + af];
   zarb1 = ξT1.inv.ξ1},
  {L, 1, 1000, 100}]
ListPlot[hassan]
{{1, {{1.09029}}}, {101, {{1.06622}}}, {201, {{1.04201}}}, {301, \
{{1.01766}}}, {401, {{0.993172}}}, {501, {{0.968559}}}, {601, \
{{0.943825}}}, {701, {{0.91898}}}, {801, {{0.89403}}}, {901, \
{{0.868985}}}}
```

I have some differential equations as below. I have tried to solve them numerically with `NDSolve` and to plot `zarb1` versus `L`. what's the problem
I want to plot `hassan` versus `L`.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix product `ξT1.inv.ξ1` gives a $1\times 1$ matrix. In order to turn it into a scalar replace the last line in the first argument of the `Table` with `(ξT1.inv.ξ1)[[1,1]]` and your plot should work.

This is what I got with only this change to your code:

[image]